# Auto-load python support code into lldb when binary loaded or shared library linked

Tags: python, lldb

For gdb, I can use either a `.gdb_debug_scripts` section or a file naming convention (`$BINARY-gdb.py` or `$LIBRARY-gdb.py`) to specify that when that object file is loaded into gdb, the extension code should be invoked.

Does LLDB have equivalent functionality?

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory solution to this problem?